# Cannot install crawler for ABP

Tags: python, firefox, firefox-addon, adblock

I'm getting errors when trying to install abpcrawler (Repository below).

https://github.com/adblockplus/abpcrawler

When running the command

```
./run.py -b /usr/bin/firefox urls.txt outputdir
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
bash-3.2# ./run.py -b /usr/bin/firefox urls.txt outputdir
Communicating with client on port 29922
['/usr/bin/firefox', '--crawler-port', '29922', '-foreground', '-profile', '/tmp/tmpgZYg1r.mozrunner']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 195, in <module>
    run()
  File "./run.py", line 178, in run
    runner.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mozrunner/base/browser.py", line 67, in start
    BaseRunner.start(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mozrunner/base/runner.py", line 102, in start
    self.process_handler.run(self.timeout, self.output_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mozprocess/processhandler.py", line 700, in run
    self.proc = self.Process([self.cmd] + self.args, **args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mozprocess/processhandler.py", line 103, in __init__
    universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something? I have Mercurial installed and am able to clone the build tools repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the error message, `/usr/bin/firefox` couldn't be started because:

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

ABP Crawler requires Firefox to be installed, it will automate Firefox in order to collect data. If Firefox is actually installed, maybe the path is `/usr/local/bin/firefox` or something similar. You can run `which firefox` from the command line if you aren't sure.

Comment: Thanks, am able to install now.